# issue with using stax2-api

Tags: java, xml, maven, stax

I wonder if anyone is familiar with stax-api and in particular stax2-api.

I am having a strange behavior in my application.

I have an Application A that depends on Java.xml.stream:stax-1.0-2

However as soon as i put org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api in my dependency, without even using it yet, the application switch to using stax2-api.

Stax2-api is presented as follow on github:

> Stax2 API is implemented natively by following Stax XML
>   implementations:
>
> Woodstox Aalto In addition, Stax2 API contains wrapper implementations
>   that can be used to support most of API on regular Stax
>   implementations like Sun SJSXP (default Stax implementation bundled
>   with JDK 1.6 and 1.7).

**API classes are in package org.codehaus.stax2.**

```
Stax2 API also contains partial Reference Implementation of many of API classes, under org.codehaus.stax2.ri: intention is to make it as painless as possible for Java Stax parser to implement full Stax2 support.

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
  <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency of stax2 are as follows:

```
    <dependencies>
            <!-- Since baseline with 4.0 is Java5, we still need to officially keep this in;
                 should drop once we go up to Java6 or 7
              -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
              <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
              <version>1.0-2</version>
              <!-- at this point, with inclusion in JDK 1.6, this should be given -->
              <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

It should be noted that my application A works well with its original dependency on ***Java.xml.stream:stax-1.0-2.***

Any idea why stax2 is used instead of stax.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean exactly by "the application switch [sic] to using stax2-api"?

Comment: I gave up on that i'm going another lib. But in case i will explain, stax2-api has a partial reference implementation of stax-api. Has the owner of the lib told me, its seems the only possiblity is shading. Because there are some package in stax2-api that are suppose to replace stax-api package. So the application uses those.

Comment: You probably misunderstood what he said (or I am misunderstanding what you are saying), because stax2-api doesn't have any packages in common with stax-api. Therefore shading won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This question does not make any sense: `stax2-api` is just an API extension that implementations may choose to implement. It has no power over anything else; does not auto-register anything.

What you might have is that inclusion of any Stax implementation in classpath will result in SPI (META-INF/services/) being added, and that may change actual Stax implementation that is loaded UNLESS you specify implementation you want (like when calling `XMLInputFactory.newFactory()`).
But this has nothing to do with Stax2 API jar.